# Reproducing a directed graph with labeled edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, edge

I am trying to implement the following graph :

[image: here].

I came up with a MWE, but I am unable to draw the curved edges. The code is shown below:

```
        \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
        \PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}  
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata}

        \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,on grid,initial/.style    ={}]
          \node[state]          (A)                        {$Author$};
          \node[state]          (P) [above right =of A]    {$Paper$};
          \node[state]          (T) [below right =of A]    {$Topic$};
          \node[state]          (V) [below right =of P]    {$Venue$};
        \tikzset{mystyle/.style={->,double=orange}} 
        \tikzset{every node/.style={fill=white}} 
        \path (V)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$publish$} (P)
              (P)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$mention$} (T)
              (T)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$mention-1$} (P)
              (P)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$write-1$} (A)
              (T)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$contain$} (T);
        \tikzset{mystyle/.style={double=orange}}   
        \tikzset{mystyle/.style={<->,relative=false,in=0,out=60,double=orange}}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use the `to[ <options> ]` syntax:

```
\draw [red, ultra thick, ->] (A.north west) to[out=190, in=170, distance=1.5cm] (A.south west);
\draw [red, ultra thick, ->] (T.-150) to[out=-80, in=-100, distance=1.5cm] (T.-30);
```

where you can specify the terminal points of the curved line via a compass direction `(A.north west)` or using an angle as in `(T.-150)`, and control the `in=`, `out=` angles along with the `distance=`:

[image]

### Notes:

- Not sure why you were doing a `\tikzset` at `\end{tikzpicture}`. I have removed that portion of the code as it has no effect here.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=3cm,on grid,initial/.style    ={}]
  \node[state]          (A)                        {$Author$};
  \node[state]          (P) [above right =of A]    {$Paper$};
  \node[state]          (T) [below right =of A]    {$Topic$};
  \node[state]          (V) [below right =of P]    {$Venue$};
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={->,double=orange}} 
\tikzset{every node/.style={fill=white}} 
\path (V)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$publish$} (P)
      (P)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$mention$} (T)
      (T)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$mention-1$} (P)
      (P)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$write-1$} (A)
      (T)     edge [mystyle]    node   {$contain$} (T);
      
\draw [red, ultra thick, ->] (A.north west) to[out=190, in=170, distance=1.5cm] (A.south west);
\draw [red, ultra thick, ->] (T.-150) to[out=-80, in=-100, distance=1.5cm] (T.-30);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So unlike the edge command, the draw command does not have a feature to label/name the edge?

Comment: The labeling is done on a `node` _not_ an `edge`. You can add a `node` to the `\draw` and label it also.